# Shell Script Not Encoding ASCII

Tags: shell, character-encoding, ascii

I downloaded a shell script to convert an OpenVPN file and certificates to a .apc file for use with Sophos UTM 9. The script can be found [here](https://www.gitorious.org/admintools/ovpn-to-apc) and appears to work quite well.

The problem is the output does not appear to be encoded (I believe that is the correct term).

When I compare the output of the script to a .apc file downloaded from the UTM in Notepad++ the script output starts with

```
\x04\x06\x04
```

whereas the correctly encoded file looks like

```
EOT BEL EOT
```

When I try to import the output of the script it fails, and I believe this is because the ASCII characters are not being encoded properly.

Is there anyway I can encode all of the \x?? to the proper characters? Or else is there any way I can make the .sh output the already encoded characters?

For reference, the shell script has functions such as

```
write_header() {
    printf "\x04\x06\x041234\x04\x04\x04\x08\x03\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x0a" > ${ApcFile}
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to post the apc header part of a correct apc file for reference?

Comment: From the output .apc 

    [EOT][BEL][EOT]1234[EOT][EOT][EOT][BS][ETX]

Answer (score 0):

You should not see any characters like `\x04` literally in your resulting file.
The script just uses hexadecimal representation for control characters.

If you execute `printf "\x04\x06test"` on your shell you should see "test", if you pipe this into a hexdumper like `xxd` you should get the following

```
# printf "\x04\x06test" | xxd
0000000: 0406 7465 7374                           ..test
```

The header sequence

```
printf "\x04\x06\x041234\x04\x04\x04\x08\x03\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x0a"
```

translates to (control characters wrapped into [] brackets for clarification)

```
[EOT] [ACK] [EOT] 1234 [EOT] [EOT] [EOT] [BS] [ETX] [FF] [NUL] [NUL] [LF]
```

the funny thing: you said the working file starts with `EOT BEL EOT (\x04 \x07 \x08)`, the output file generated by the script starts with `EOT ACK EOT` (which makes sense)

counter-questions:

- do you see control characters in their hex representation literally when watching at your output file in a text editor like vi?
- Which kind of operating system are you executing this on?
- fun question: `.- .-. . / -.-- --- ..- / .-. . .-.. .- - . -.. / - --- / ... .- -- ..- . .-.. / -- --- .-. ... . / ... - --- .--.`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Michel,

When I execute, `printf "\x04\x06test"` I just see test and when I pipe it to xxd I see what you described.

When I open the working file in vi I see the control characters highlighted in blue whereas when I open the not-working file (generated by the shell script) I see the literal `\x04\x06\x04`. I am not sure why the shell script is outputting the hex representation instead of the control characters themselves.

Comment: I am running the shell script on Ubuntu Server but I downloaded the files in Windows and copied them over to a Samba share on the server.

Comment: `-. --- / ..- -. ..-. --- .-. - ..- -. .- - . .-.. -.-- / -. --- - / ... - --- .--.`